# SED - Replace every comma outside double quotes for a newline (Bash)

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I'm trying to replace all the commas outside of double quotes with a new line.

```
echo 'this "ok,hi",hello,how' | sed "s/,/\n/g"
```

The above command is resulting all the values in a new line.

```bash
this "ok
hi"
hello
how
```

but, I want my sed command to give result something like

```
this ok,hi
hello
how
```

As ok,hi is enclosed in double quotes, I'm expecting them to come in a single line.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ echo 'this "ok,hi",hello,how' | sed -E 's/("([^"]*)")?,/\2\n/g'
this ok,hi
hello
how
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this, using just `grep`:

```
$ echo 'this "ok, hi",hello,how' | grep -oP '(?<=").*?(?=")|(?<=,)\w+'
ok, hi
hello
how
```

Check [rexex101 explanations](https://regex101.com/r/SHfI3P/1)

Comment: that's just a corner case, question remains the same

Comment: Changed my answer to use only `grep`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `gnu-awk` then:

```bash
s='this "ok,hi",hello,how'

awk '{print gensub(/("([^"]*)")?,/, "\\2\n", "g")}' <<< "$s"

this ok,hi
hello
how
```

Another `gnu-awk` using `FPAT`:

```bash
awk -v FPAT='([^",]*"[^"]*")?[^",]*(,|$)' '{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
      gsub(/"|,$/, "", $i)
      print $i
   }
}' <<< "$s"

this ok,hi
hello
how
```